# Need help to update supervisor in Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a employee table , from where I am finding out the supervisor(team lead) and the manager details based on the User ID .  I have a SSIS package which appends newly created Users into my table.
Below is what i am doing currently .

- appending newly created user ID into my Sql table from the master table.
- finding the supervisor and the manager , based on the employee USER ID.

Now , when an existing employee changes his manager or the supervisor, how can I update the new changes from the master table to my sql table. I dont want to truncate and load the table either since this table is used in an application.

here is the query:

-- load new employee details

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Active_Directory_COE]
(
    [USER_ID]
  , [USER_TYPE_NM]
  , [USER_CLASS]
  , [LAST_NM]
  , [FIRST_NM]
  , [MIDDLE_INIT]
  , [EMAIL_ADDRESS]
  , [EMP_JOB_DESC]
  , [BUSINESS_UNIT_CD]
  , [BUSINESS_UNIT_NM]
  , [BUSINESS_SEGMENT]
  , [SUPERVISOR_ID]
  , [EMP_FULL_NM]
  , [MANAGER_NAME]
  , [SUPERVISOR_NAME]
  , [SUPERVISOR_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
  , [MANAGER_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
  , [TEAM]
  , [REGION]
  , [SUB_REGION]
  , [SALES_OFFICE]
  , [SALES_GROUP]
  , [EMPLOYEE_STATUS]
  , [SURVEY_GROUP]
  , [SURVEY_APPLICABLE]
  , [REGION_CSSC]
  , [SALES_ORG]
  , [SALES_OFFICE_MULTIPLE]
  , [TE_JOINING_DT]
)
       SELECT 
           [A1].[USER_ID]
         , [A1].[USER_TYPE_NM]
         , [A1].[USER_CLASS]
         , [A1].[LAST_NM]
         , [A1].[FIRST_NM]
         , [A1].[MIDDLE_INIT]
         , [A1].[EMAIL_ADDRESS]
         , [A1].[EMP_JOB_DESC]
         , [A1].[BUSINESS_UNIT_CD]
         , [A1].[BUSINESS_UNIT_NM]
         , [A1].[BUSINESS_SEGMENT]
         , [A1].[SUPERVISOR_ID]
         , [A1].[EMP_FULL_NM]
         , [D].[EMP_FULL_NM] AS [Manager_Name]
         , [C].[EMP_FULL_NM] AS [Supervisor_name]
         , [C].[EMAIL_ADDRESS] AS [Supr_Email_AD]
         , [D].[EMAIL_ADDRESS] AS [Mangaer_Email_Ad]
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , NULL
         , [A1].[SERVICE_CREDIT_DT]
       FROM
(
    SELECT 
        [A].[USER_ID]
      , [A].[USER_TYPE_NM]
      , [A].[USER_CLASS]
      , [A].[LAST_NM]
      , [A].[FIRST_NM]
      , [A].[MIDDLE_INIT]
      , [A].[EMAIL_ADDRESS]
      , [A].[EMP_JOB_DESC]
      , [A].[BUSINESS_UNIT_CD]
      , [A].[BUSINESS_UNIT_NM]
      , [A].[BUSINESS_SEGMENT]
      , [A].[SUPERVISOR_ID]
      , [A].[EMP_FULL_NM]
      , [A].[SERVICE_CREDIT_DT]
    FROM [dbo].[Active_Directory] [A]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Active_Directory_COE] [B]
         ON [A].[USER_ID] = [B].[USER_ID]
    WHERE [B].[USER_ID] IS NULL
) [A1]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Active_Directory] [C]
ON [C].[USER_ID] = [A1].[SUPERVISOR_ID]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Active_Directory] [D]
ON [C].[SUPERVISOR_ID] = [D].[USER_ID];
```

Comment: What have you attempted to catch this update so far?  [An update trigger?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have a query to add the new items into the sql table from the master, but i am not able to figure out how to capture the changes in the master table and update the same in sql table.
example 
user A manager is User B , later it is changed to user C.  How can I update this change from manager B to C into my sql table

Comment: I understand you have a employee and a master tables?  Can you show us all tables defs?

Comment: An image of a bunch of column headers is not helpful on multiple levels. Post actual DDL, sample data, and an actual example of what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: You have the query when adding a new user.  Please show us that query.  You only need the query when there are a changes (update).  Nothing to do when there is a deletion?

Comment: Yes it is needed only when there is a change, i have edited the question with the query now

Comment: Any help? please suggest